# How do I safely farm mid while Pudge is missing?

Tags: dota-2

Here's the situation, I like playing QE Invoker mid, but I have troubles when I play against Pudge. I will always crush him in lane. I always harrass him so he never comes in for any last hits. I will keep creeps in between us so he cannot hook me. Basically, the laning phase is very easy.

But once Pudge hits level 6+, (if he's good) he will start to nonstop roam around the map and gank. I am then presented with these problems:

- If he's good, he will get smoke, and wards become useless. I will never really know where he is on the map.
- Because I do not know where he is I can't position myself to block a hook.

When it reaches that point in the game where I don't know where Pudge is, what do I do to safely continue farming gold/exp? It seems there is nothing I can do to stop the risk of being helplessly hooked by a smoked-up Pudge.

PS. This question works for any hero really, but if you have some tips that could be applied to Invoker specifically that would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you are really affraid of being hooked versus Pudge, having wards high ground is the best solution.

You can ask your support to put up wards so you will always see where pudge is (see screenshot at the end).

Then as an Invoker you can put an early point in wex just fot ghost walking away. This might delay your dual forge spirit (in the QE built) but if you really feel insecure that might be the best way to go.

With any mid hero you have to not make the basic mistake versus pudge which is : try to escape the rot by running. If you ever get hooked, trade hit with pudge and burst him with your spell. If you try to run you're almost certainly dead. Pudge has a really low armor at low level so your right click damage will hurt him badly, plus remember that the rot inflict damage to himself too so you can often turn a hook into a kill for yourself, just dont be afraid to manfight him. Pudge players tend to get overconfident when they land a hook, prove them they should not.

Another great tip is : rot does not dispell healing salve until its level 4, so you can use a salve to get some hp back between 2 hit and that might save your life.

**Screenshots**

Those wards' position can be used to avoid any kind of early ganks. You can watch the minimap to have an idea on what vision it gives.

When you are on the *Radiant* side :

[image]
[image]

When you are on the *Dire* side :

[image]
[image]

This last observer is usefull to scout mid highgrounds at all time to avoid hooks (you can place it on both side but preferably the enemy's side) :

[image]

Comment: Those are some good wards, those should solve my problems. One thing is that in 6.79 [smoke goes through truesight](http://en.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/1oq11m/true_sight_does_not_reveal_smoke_of_deceit_in_679/). Still, looks like this will keep you safe most of the time. I guess if you see Pudge has smoke you just have to be really carefull.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus11 yo'ure welcome, the point about smoke bug me, gotta check that this seem a bit too OP for me but that 6.79 patch is weir anyway ;)

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus11 oh god its true, why would icefrog do that T_T, well anyway the ward spots are good, just play safe. Smoke break within 1025 range and level 7 hook has 1300 range so you have a fairly low margin to react

Comment: Yeah I guess you could just have an escape spell ready (tornado, def. blast, ghost walk) if you see he has smoke, and pray to god you can cast it fast O_o

Comment: +1 nice answer, and couldnt resist: http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/9/9a/Anti_blink_03.mp3

Answer (score 0):

You can farm with your forge sprites if you can or try to keep them around you depend on your location so they will get hooks. But being a Pudge player, it's kinda hard to do anything to Pudge if you get hook and you're Invoker. You can buy a Eul's and tornado yourself as soon as you get hooked to give you some time to think. You can also Force Staff away before you get dismembered.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  Can you edit this post to make it read a bit clearer?

Answer (score -1):

Do not allow your wave of creeps to be far from your tower.